# Grouping raw data into columns of data Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a bunch of raw data that is basically categorized into three categories (ignore three constraint, let's just say n categories). I want to split this into multiple columns where each column is its own category. Example:

Data:

```
Type    Value
1       5
3       6
1       2
2       8
2       4
3       5
2       3
```

Output desired in a new location on the spreadsheet:

```
1       2       3
-----------------
5       8       6
2       4       5
        3
```

I have looked at Pivot tables but don't exactly understand how to accomplish it using that. So, I would appreciate help in either understanding the Pivot tables approach, or some other approach.

I looked at other posts, and couldn't find anything that exactly matched this requirement, so please don't flag duplicate. Also, I want to avoid using VBA as this is part of a statistics project.

Comment: Write a VBA sub procedure using a scripting dictionary. The *keys* would be *Types* and each key's *item* would be an array of the associated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with a pivot table you need a helper column, so the data does not get summarized into one row. In the screenshot, I've used the following formula to determine how many times the type of that row has already shown.

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()),[@Type])
```

[image]

This column can then be used in the Rows area of the pivot. The Type goes into the columns area and the value into the values area. Remove any totals and hide column E if it upsets your sheet design.

If you have a version of Excel with the **new Dynamic Array functions**, you can use the Filter function. In the following screenshot, the type values 1, 2 and 3 were manually typed into cells E2 to G2. Then this formula goes into E3 and is copied to the right:

```
=FILTER($B:$B,$A:$A=E$2)
```

[image]

Dynamic arrays are available to Insiders in Office 365 and will hopefully be available to all Office 365 users soon.

Comment: Interesting approach. Thank you! That makes sense. I was struggling to separate the values from a single field such as sum into multiple fields. This fixes that.